# How to redirect implicitly wordpress page to a specific link

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a page on wordpress called "Animal" and this page will get by **default this link**:
"www.example.com/animal" 
and this page will be added to a menu with wordpress menu editor, so once we click on "Animal" at at the menu, **instead** to visit the page with this link: 
"www.example.com/animal"
 I want it to **redirect** me to this link:
 "www.example.com/category/animal-list"

and this please without using **meta**
 How could I do that?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: you can achive this through the settings, in the permalink structure.

Comment: But this second link exist I want just to rediret to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Go to DashBord >> Appearance >> Menus:

And then:

Go to the widget >> Custom links

Look at the picture (it is in French)

[Here you add anything you want to the menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7oJD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Abdelaziz Mirad,

There are several ways to do this but here are a few. As a quick solution you could do this using a plugin like this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

**OR** via .htaccess using this code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /animal(.*) /category/animal-list/$1
```

**OR** you may be able to adjust the settings for your permalink structure. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying man :) I didn't try what you suggested, your answer look very interesting! I solved the problem before i saw it

Comment: No problem @AbdelazizMirad, I'm glad you found a solution. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by 301 .htaccess redirect,

```
Redirect 301 /animal www.example.com/category/animal-list
```

Write this code to htaccess file .